# Linking certain C++ libraries only when necessary

Tags: c++

I integrated Tesseract into our own C++ library, whereas it was mentioned that Tesseract may take too much time and spaces and **Tesseract ISN'T ALWAYS NEEDED** when our library is being used as we also have our own deep learning models for the purpose of text recognition, so I wonder if it's possible to link certain libraries on demand, both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Investigate `LoadLibrary` for Windows.

Comment: load them on demand. dlopen(3) for linux, LoadLibraryEx on Windows